# Remove libvirt with docker running on same machine

Tags: docker, suse, libvirt

I am running SUSE Linux Enterprise 12. For security reasons, I want to uninstall libvirt since kvm/quemu VMs are no longer needed on the machine. At the same time, we are running docker and I am not sure whether or not docker is using some part of the libvirt installation.

Is it safe to uninstall libvirt and everything associated with kvm/quemu VMs while keeping docker running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker and libvirt are completely separate software stacks which should have no dependencies on each other. So there should be no risk to docker from uninstalling libvirt, and vica-versa.